# AWS S3 bucket region-less webpage hosting

Tags: amazon-s3, bucket

Having read a lot of the aws documentation and not finding anything relevant.

How to host a website directly from my S3 bucket say:
s3-myhost-w.amazonaws.com

when I try to access the site directly:

```
<Message>
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
</Message>
<Bucket>s3-myhost-w.amazonaws.com</Bucket>
<Endpoint>s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>
```

because when I select the option to host a website I am forced to use this url:
http://s3.amazonaws.com/s3-myhost-w.amazonaws.com

OR how to at least redirect all requests

From http://s3.amazonaws.com/s3-myhost-w.amazonaws.com

To:http://s3-myhost-w.amazonaws.com

so that I can serve content using the direct url?

EDIT:
DNS can be configured using Route53 . I am closing this question

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  Since the URLs you've used implies that your bucket name is either `s3-myhost-w` or `s3-myhost-w.amazonaws.com`, neither of which is an actual bucket in S3 (at least not at the moment), nor would really be seemingly meaningful or desirable bucket names.  Your answer doesn't actually describe what you did to solve whatever it was you were trying to solve.

Comment: ...however, based on what I *think* you were attempting, I've marked this question as a duplicate of another question that provides an answer.

Comment: Yes, for privacy reasons this was not the actual name but a similar name.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: DNS can be configured using Route53